# how to print keys of dictionary in coordinate way?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
dic2={(0,0):'⬃',(-2,-2):'⇩',(-2,-3):'⇩'}
```

I would like to print the dictionary's values and they can be shown as the position I have allocated. How I can print that?

Comment: try this `dic2.keys()`

Comment: You can use `list(dic2)` as alternative of `dic2.keys()`.

Comment: @Corralien I would like to print the values not keys. like ⬃ in (0,0) ⇩ in (-2,-2)

Comment: `list(dic2.values())` gives you `['⬃', '⇩', '⇩']`

Comment: @xzha_athena. Oh sorry. Can you check the title of your question?

Comment: As of python 3.7 the insertion order is preserved, if that is what you mean by _the position I have allocated_. Otherwise, show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to print your values on a grid at the coordinates specified by the key.

Let's assume a square matrix of size `N`. I will show empty cells as `⋅` for clarity.

You can use:

```
N = 5

dic2={(0,0):'⬃',(-2,-2):'⇩',(-2,-3):'⇩'}

matrix = [['⋅' for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]

for (x,y), v in dic2.items():
    matrix[x][y] = v
    
print('\n'.join(map(''.join, matrix)))
```

Alternatively, you wan rework the dictionary and use:

```
N = 5

dic3 = {(i if i>=0 else N+i, j if j>=0 else N+j):v for (i,j),v in dic2.items()}
# {(0, 0): '⬃', (3, 3): '⇩', (3, 2): '⇩'}

print('\n'.join([''.join([dic3.get((i, j), '⋅')
                 for i in range(N)]) for j in range(N)]))
```

Output:

```
⬃⋅⋅⋅⋅
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅
⋅⋅⇩⇩⋅
⋅⋅⋅⋅⋅
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* print them, below is a version of the first suggestion in [mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75659819/6146136), where you initiate a matrix full of a single character and then fill it at certain indices [that correspond to the coordinates] according to `dic2`.

```py
bgChar = '+' # '▪' # '●' # ' ' # '⁜' # set a "background" character
dic2 = {(0,0):'⬃', (-2,-2):'⇩', (-2,-3):'⇩'}

getRange = lambda l: (min(l), max(l))
x_min, x_max = getRange([c[0] for c in dic2])
y_min, y_max = getRange([c[1] for c in dic2])

myCanvas = [[f'{bgChar:^3}']*(x_max-x_min+3) for _ in range(y_max-y_min+3)]
for (x,y),v in dic2.items(): 
    myCanvas[y+1-y_min][x+1-x_min] = f'{v:^3}'

print(' '*3+''.join([f'{i+1+x_min:^3}' for i in range(x_max - x_min + 3)]))
for i, r in list(enumerate(myCanvas))[::-1]: 
    print(''.join([f'{i-1+y_min:^3}']+r))
```

> [image: view results]

<sup>I added the numbers for the axes and also changed the character (`bgChar`) in "coordinates" that are not covered in `dic2` (because I felt like using space `' '` made it a bit hard to figure out the coordinates of printed arrows).</sup>

---

However, as you can see, variations in character width mess up the alignment of x-coordinates, so it might be better to **plot** rather than print, using something like [`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) which has a handy method called [`annotate`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-annotate-in-python/).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic2={(0,0):'⬃',(-2,-2):'⇩',(-2,-3):'⇩'}
getRange = lambda l: (min(l), max(l))
x_min, x_max = getRange([c[0] for c in dic2])
y_min, y_max = getRange([c[1] for c in dic2])

fig, myCanvas = plt.subplots()
myCanvas.set_xlim(x_min-1, x_max+1)
myCanvas.set_ylim(y_min-1, y_max+1)

for xy, v in dic2.items(): myCanvas.annotate(v, xy, xy)
plt.show()
```

[image: opplt]